# How to export Windows Scheduled task history

Tags: windows-task-scheduler

On Win2008 R2 - Is there an interface I can go to, or a command I can run, to export the history of one particular task from Windows Task Scheduler?  I'll even take all the tasks and then filter the results.  The best I can come up with so far is to search in the Event Viewer, using the Event Log C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler%4Operational.evtx for the task in question, and record by hand the time of day it stopped.

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 5):

I found logs for Task Scheduler in 
C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\Microsoft-Windows-TaskScheduler%4Operational.evtx
When I double click on the file it opens the Event Viewer in that file.

Also, opening the Event Viewer from Administrative Tools I can drill down to Event Viewer >> Applications and Services Logs >> Microsoft >> Windows >> TaskScheduler >> Operational to view the logs I would see from the Task Scheduler Library.

hope this helps -
Alan

Comment: This solution worked for me too. Once it opens up in "Event Viewer", you can select "Save All Events As..." and export it to CSV/TSV for analysis.

Thanks for the answer. I can't seem to find any solution at all from Google.

Answer (score 0):

With the release [v0.19.0](https://github.com/prometheus-community/windows_exporter/releases/tag/v0.19.0) of the [Windows Exporter](https://github.com/prometheus-community/windows_exporter) (maintained by the Prometheus Community), you can export Scheduled Task metrics, which can then be scraped by a monitoring solution of your choice (Prometheus itself i.e.) if that's an option for you.